# Django context doesn't load after post

Tags: python, forms, django-views, render

I'm trying to pass "message_name" to index.html through the form but the context does not render after submitting the form. It appears a blank page. I can see through the page inspector that the text was submitted but the content doesn't show.

I imagine this should be really easy but I could not find solution till now.

Thank you in advance for your help.

#views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Home, About, Profile, Category, Skills, Item, Audiogil, ImageSkills
from django.core.paginator import Paginator


def index(request):
    # Home
    home = Home.objects.latest('updated')

    # About
    about = About.objects.latest('updated')
    #profiles = Profile.objects.filter(about=about)
    profiles = Profile.objects.all()

    # Skills
    categories = Category.objects.all()

    skillsimage = ImageSkills.objects.latest('updated')

    # Videos
    videos = Item.objects.all()

    # Setup video pagination
    p = Paginator(Item.objects.all(), 2)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    video_list = p.get_page(page)

    # Audios
    audios = Audiogil.objects.all()

    
    context = {
        'home': home,
        'about': about,
        'profiles': profiles,
        'categories': categories,
        'videos': videos,
        'video_list': video_list,
        'audios': audios,
        'skillsimage': skillsimage,
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        message_name = request.POST['message-name']
        message_email = request.POST['message-email']
        message = request.POST['message']

        return render(request, 'index.html', {'message_name':message_name})


    
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

#template
....

```
  <!--===== CONTACT =====-->
  <section class="contact section" id="contact">
    <h2 class="section-title">Contacto - {{ message_name }}</h2>

    <div class="contact__container bd-grid">
      <div class="contact__info">
        <h3 class="contact__subtitle">EMAIL</h3>
        <span class="contact__text">info.mail.com</span>
      </div>

      <form action="{% url 'index' %}" class="contact__form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="contact__inputs">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="message-name" class="contact__input" />
          <input type="mail" placeholder="Email" name="message-email" class="contact__input" />
        </div>

        <textarea
          name="message"
          id=""
          cols="0"
          rows="10"
          class="contact__input"
        ></textarea>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="contact__button" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: when you have POST then you run `return render(request, 'index.html', {'message_name':message_name})` and there is no `content`. You send only `message_name` - so what did you expect ? If you want to send `context` and `message_name` then you should add `message_name` to `context` - `context["message_name"] = message_name` - and render with `context` - `render(..., context)`

Comment: we can't see full code and run it - maybe you have some `{{ if }}` which skips HTML when there is no value in `context`

Comment: Thank you for your replies that made me think about it and actually I could solve it passing all the context again: ```return render(request, 'index.html', context={'home': home, 'about': about, 'profiles': profiles, 'categories': categories,         'videos': videos, 'video_list': video_list, 'audios': audios, 'skillsimage': skillsimage, 'message_name': message_name,})     return render(request, 'index.html', context)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', {'message_name':message_name})
```

...to this:

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

...if your intent is to pick up the context dictionary you have declared above your `POST` method.

If you want to add in additional context such as `message_name`, you could do something like:

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        context['message_name'] = request.POST['message-name']
        message_email = request.POST['message-email']
        message = request.POST['message']
        # seems like you're missing (or not showing) more logic here...
```

...which you can do once you have declared a context dictionary somewhere up above, as you have.

One last word: You have a fair number of model queries going on in this view.  Are any these models related via OneToOne, ForeignKey, or ManyToMany relations?  If so, consider fewer queries with the `select_related()` and/or `prefetch_related()` methods for the sake of efficiency.  More about those [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) in the Django docs.  You can access or iterate through related objects in your template, for example:

```
{{queried_object.related_object.field_value}}
```

Comment: Thank you, Milo Persic! Regarding your "Last Word" I will read the documentation about that. Keep up the good work!

Comment: You too my friend.  Happy coding!